# Image overflow view - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have that view :

```
<View style={styles.aboutView}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image source={{uri: this.state.community.logo}} style={styles.logo} />
        </View>
        <Text></Text>
</View>
```

and this is the StyleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
aboutView:{
 padding:5,
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 borderColor: 'rgb(238, 238, 238)',
 borderBottomWidth : 1,
 borderTopWidth : 1,
 height:80,
 overflow:'visible'
},
logo:{
 width:100,
 height:100,
 borderRadius :50,
 overflow:'visible'
},
logoContainer:{
 marginTop:-30,
 width:100,
 height:100,
 borderRadius :50,
 shadowColor: "#000000", 
 shadowOpacity: 0.8, 
 shadowRadius: 2, 
 shadowOffset: {
   height: 1,
   width: 0
 }, 
 elevation:8,
 overflow:'visible'
}
});
```

this is the result I get:
[image: Result]

As you can see the logoContainer gets cropped on the aboutView top boarder. I am trying to make the logoContainer overflow the aboutView, as I want the image to overflow the aboutView, I have tried several methods so far but nothing seems to work, it seems like the overflow property has no effect.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Capture]

As you can see the circled image overflows and not getting cropped at the top of the view

Comment: can you restate your objective? I don't understand what you're after when you say "I am trying to make the logoContainer overflow the aboutView, as I want the image to overflow the aboutView"

Comment: I've added a picture of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing a photo of your intention. That's much clearer. Try this...

```
<View style={styles.aboutView} />
<View style={styles.logoContainer}>
  <Image source={{uri: this.state.community.logo}} style={styles.logo} />
</View>
<Text></Text>
```

There's no z-index in react-native, but views following other views will be higher in the stack, so you can order your code strategically to achieve the desired affect.

Comment: The thing is that the text needs to be next to the image and not beneath it (see updated photo)

Comment: your approach to the solution should still be the same. If you setup something on rnplay.org that I can fiddle with, I'll see what I can do, but my guess is that you've got all the info you now need to work this out.